# Working with really long String in Java (Fibonacci problem)

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm working on Fibonacci problem that return a string 0 or 1 and count them by a string that give by input

[image: my problem table]

```
f(0) = "0", f(1) = "1" , f(2) = "10"
```

and when I run my code in bigger n my java is error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:172)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:538)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:174)
    at fibo.sfibo(fibo.java:16)
    at fibo.main(fibo.java:42)
```

I think it because I store too long string in variable can anyone can help me how to deal with a long string

```
static String sfibo(int n){
    String a = "0";
    String b = "1";
    String c = "";
    int i=0;
    for (i=2;i<=n;i++){
        c = b+a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return c;    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String check = sc.nextLine();
    String text = sfibo(n);
    int lastindex = text.indexOf(check);
    int counter =1;
    while(1==1){
        lastindex = text.indexOf(check, lastindex+1);

        if (lastindex>=0){
            counter++;  
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
   System.out.println(counter);
   sc.close();
}
```

edit: I have try to use `BigInteger` to store data but it still overflow

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range
        at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.reportOverflow(BigInteger.java:1151)
        at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.checkRange(BigInteger.java:1146)
        at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:1121)
        at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.shiftLeft(BigInteger.java:3315)
        at fibo.sfibo(fibo.java:10)
        at fibo.main(fibo.java:22)
```

but at this time i can run `sfibo(45)` last time was error at `sfibo(43)` this is my code

```
static BigInteger sfibo(int n){
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger c = new BigInteger("2");
        for (int i=3;i<=n;i++){
            BigInteger tmp = c;
            c = c.shiftLeft(b.bitLength()).add(b);
            b = tmp;
        }
        return c;
}
```

Comment: So what do you mean with "bigger n" ?

Comment: like when i call sfibo(40) it can run, but when I call it with sfibo(50) it shows me the error

Comment: Since you're only interested in the length of the string, which equals fib(n) in the conventional sense (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ...), you could save a lot of steps here (not to mention CPU cycles and heap space) by simply calculating that number.

Comment: fib(50) is about 1.2E10, so i would expect you need at least 50G or so heapspace to store the string

Comment: Why aren't you using `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` for this? `String` is the worst possible choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string, assuming a modern VM, takes roughly 1 byte per character, as long as we say that the string only contains the `0` and the `1` character, with some tens of overhead on top of that. So, if your string contains about 500 zeroes and ones, the memory load of that string is about 510 bytes. Given that you're running out of memory, forget the 10, it's dwarfed. It's about how many 'digits' are in there.

An actual *number* Uses **one bit** per zero or one instead of one byte. It's literally 8x more efficient. Unfortunately, you can't *just* use a `long` - the whole point here is that your fib numbers are waaaay larger than what fits in a long (which is 64 bits).

Instead, you want an arbitrary length number, but where each binary digit takes up no more than one bit.

There are a few ways to accomplish this, but the most obvious and easiest one is to use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html).

This buys you about a factor 8: Where your code works until a number hits, say, 1 million zeroes/ones, replacing `String` with `BigInteger` would get you as far as 8 million zeroes/ones.

However, that doesn't actually buy you much: Fib grows quite fast.

To get further, you simply can't use memory anymore and you'd have to plug in a 4TB harddisk and start writing your bits to it.

It'll take days at that point, no doubt.

In general you need to take a step back: If you're trying to calculate Fib(10000000), why, and what aspects of the output do you actually need? These numbers are too large for simple computer work, you need to get 'smart' and figure out which specific aspect you need. Surely it's not 'every digit', as there are literally trillions of those.

Comment: What do you mean by replacing String with Biginteger? I don't quite understand when I convert string to Biginteger my last Fib is store in Biginteger right? but if I need to fine next term of Fib, How can I find if my last term is store in Biginteger or I need to Biginteger concat? (I actually need to calculate just Fib(100) it's my homework thank you from explaination)

Comment: You have decided to solve the problem of representing your fibonacci results in memory with: "I shall represent them with a String, containing 0 and 1 characters". There is no optimizing once you've made that choice; instead, go back and make a different choice: Represent them using a BigInteger object and not a String object.

Comment: if I treat them like integers how can I find Fib(2), Fib(2) comes from "1" + "0" right ? but I have no idea how to deal it with an integer

Comment: By fetching the bits from the BigInteger object. Peruse the API.